# Reference to current class xaml Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I got the following code:

```
namespace SomeApp
{
  public partial class MyClass : PhoneApplicationPage, IValueConverter
  {

    SOME METHODS...

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return true;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return true;

    }

  }
}
```

I would like to bind this class to a ValueConverter of a RadioButton. Is there any way to reference to the current class I'm working with? For example:

> `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
>
>   x:Class="SomeApp.MyClass"
>
>   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeApp">`
>
> `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
>
>           <local:MyClass x:Key="myClass"/>
>
>       </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>`
>
> `<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myClass}}"/>`

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: public class MyClass : IValueConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First  using your page as a converter don't seem like a good idea, it's better practice to separate the converter fonctionality in a separate class. Particularly it would be a very bad idea to create a StaticResources of a converter created that way as it will use a lot of unessessary memory to create the whole page.

The only thing a converter can be binded in xaml is a StaticResource so you will not be able to do it in xaml but if you really want to do it you could do it by creating the binding from code behind (for example in the constructor of the page):

```cs
Binding binding=new Binding();
binding.Converter = this;
myRadioButton.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the advices. =) and what if I just want to refer to the current class in XAML?? not thru Static Resource...

Comment: If is not a converter (which support only StaticResource), you can refer to the current class using ElementName:   set a name on the root of you xaml and use the following binding where you want to reference the current page: {Binding ElementName=myClass} (where my class is the name you assigned on to the root